# How do I get the name of the current directory in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, directory

How do I get the name of the current directory in Ruby? All I've found is `File.dirname(__FILE__)`, but that only returns `.` and I want the actual name. How do I do this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
dirname = File.basename(Dir.getwd)
```

`File.basename()` returns the base name even when its argument is the path of a directory.

To get **absolute path**, **[Dir.pwd](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M002316)** seems to do the trick.

Comment: This actually returns name of folder from which is script run. Eg. If I am  in `/my/folderx` and run `./test/runme.eb` (which contains `dirname = File.basename(Dir.getwd)`) than `dirname => 'folderx'` not `test`

Answer (score 39):

In Ruby 2.0 or greater, you can use [`Kernel#__dir__`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__):

```
__dir__
```

From the docs:

> Returns the canonicalized absolute path of the directory of the file
>   from which this method is called.

Comment: As mentioned in the question - "that only returns . and I want the actual name" (it is true also for ruby >=2.0.0, for example Ruby 2.3.3).

Answer (score 12):

```
File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
```

Comment: Why the two `dirnames`?

Comment: I believe this is a typo, however, it will work both ways: with the extra call to dirname and without: `File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))`

Comment: The path of the script itself and the current working directory may be different. This is for the path of the script itself, not the current directory as far as I know.